# Bootcamp Error: The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition (not a duplicate)

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition

I am running Mojave, trying to install the latest version of Windows 10.

I had this error, so followed the instructions here:

[Bootcamp issue: The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343543/bootcamp-issue-the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-p)

Then started Bootcamp, and while Bootcamp was running, an update restarted my iMac, and now I am getting the same error, but there seems to be just 1 partition.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         2.0 TB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.1 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            1.1 TB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.2 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
```

So now I am stuck and can't install Windows.

I would really appreciate some help, since I have already spent 20h with this Windows partition (tried updating the old one, it got corrupted, after hours of trying to fix it, tried re-installing it with Microsoft Tool, it failed, and now when trying to reinstall it with Bootcamp, somehow it failed again).

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Ran the command, here's the result:

```
The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Shrinking APFS Physical Store disk1s2 from 2,000,189,177,856 to 1,699,999,997,952 bytes
Shrinking APFS data structures
Shrinking partition
Modifying partition map
Volume name      : BOOTCAMP
Partition offset : 3320723456 sectors (1700210409472 bytes)
Volume size      : 586305536 sectors (300188434432 bytes)
Bytes per sector : 512
Bytes per cluster: 131072
FAT offset       : 2048 sectors (1048576 bytes)
# FAT sectors    : 18432
Number of FATs   : 1
Cluster offset   : 20480 sectors (10485760 bytes)
# Clusters       : 2290176
Volume Serial #  : 5d117270
Bitmap start     : 2
Bitmap file size : 286272
Upcase start     : 5
Upcase file size : 5836
Root start       : 6
Mounting disk
1 new disk created or changed due to APFS operation
Disk from APFS operation: disk1s3
Finished APFS operation
```

Here's the output of diskutil list

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1.7 TB     disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                300.2 GB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.8 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            765.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.2 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US... +4.9 GB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Time Machine Backups    2.1 TB     disk4s2
```

Comment: You can try the command `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 0`. It is a long shot, but is worth a try. BTW: What is *Microsoft Tool*?

Comment: @DavidAnderson already tried it, didn't work :( Tried multiple times to use first aid after booting in recovery. First aid worked fine, no errors, but still no success.

Comment: OK. Try the command `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 xG ExFAT BOOTCAMP 0`, where `x` is the size in Gigabytes you want to retain on the HDD for  macOS. For example, if you want to give Windows 300 GB, then enter `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 1700G ExFAT BOOTCAMP 0`. If this succeeds, then post a command and I will provide instructions for installing Windows. You will need a 16 GB or larger flash drive. Also, if the command succeeds, then edit your question and add the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I ran the command, and edited my post with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Graphical User Interface (GUI) provided by Microsoft to install Windows 10 on `disk1` of your Mac, you would have to remove the `disk1s2` partition containing the APFS Container `disk2`. To keep this partition and also install Windows 10 to this drive, you will have to use the Windows 10 Command Line Interface (CLI). Basically, you will need to run the `diskpart` and `dism` commands in a Command Prompt window.

### How to Create a Windows 10 USB Installer.

Creating the Windows 10 USB installer is fairly simple. The steps are given below.

1. Use the Disk Utility application to erase the USB flash drive. Choose `WINSTALL` for the name, `ExFAT` for the format and `Master Boot Record` for the scheme.
2. Use the Finder application to open (mount) the 64 bit Windows 10 ISO file. The latest release of Windows 10 can be downloaded from [this Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
3. Copy the entire contents of mounted Windows 10 ISO volume to the flash drive.
4. Use the Boot Camp Assistant application to download the Windows Support Software. Look for `Download Windows Support Software` under `Action` on the menu bar.
5. Copy the entire contents of the downloaded Windows Support Software folder to the flash drive.

If you followed the above steps correctly, then you should at least find the `$WinPEDriver$` and `efi` folders in the root folder of the flash drive.

### How to Boot from a Windows 10 USB Installer and Open a Command Prompt Window.

1. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until then Start Manager icons appear.
2. Choose the external drive icon with the label `EFI Boot`.
3. You should see a window similar to the image shown below. When this occurs, press the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key combination. A Command Prompt window should appear.

   [image]

### How to Create the Partitions Needed for Windows 10.

The instructions given below were take directly from the Microsoft website: [UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions). Since you already have a GPT partitioned drive, the appropriate changes were made to the procedure given in the linked website.

1. Enter the command given below to start the disk partitioning application.

   ```
   diskpart
   ```
2. The commands give below should assign the temporary drive letter `S` to the system partition created when you installed macOS.

   ```
   select disk 1
   select partition 1
   assign letter=s
   ```
3. Enter the commands given below to select the `BOOTCAMP` partition. Use the output to confirm the label is `BOOTCAMP`. **Proceed only if the label is `BOOTCAMP`.**

   ```
   select partition 3
   detail partition
   ```
4. Enter the command given below to delete the Boot Camp partition.

   ```
   delete partition
   ```
5. The next command will create a Microsoft Reserved (MSR) partition.

   ```
   create partition msr size=16
   ```
6. Enter the commands given below to recreate the Boot Camp partition, then shrink the partition to make space for the Recovery Tools partition. Next the partition is formatted. Finally, the temporary drive letter `W` is assigned to the partition.

   ```
   create partition primary
   shrink minimum=800
   format fs=ntfs label=BOOTCAMP quick
   assign letter=w
   ```
7. Enter the commands given below to create the Recovery Tools partition.

   ```
   create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
   format fs=ntfs label=Recovery quick
   gpt attributes=0X8000000000000001
   ```
8. Enter the command below to get a list of volumes. Note which drive letter (Ltr) was assigned to volume with the label `WINSTALL`. Th rest of this answer assumes the drive letter is `D`. If you get a different drive letter, then make the appropriate substitutions.

   ```
   list volume
   ```
9. Enter the commands given below to exit `diskpart` command. Proceed and install Windows 10.

   ```
   exit
   ```

### Transfer the Windows 10 files to the Boot Camp Partition.

1. First, enter the command given below to determine name of the file containing the Windows files. I will assume the displayed file name is `install.wim`.

   ```
   dir  /b  D:\Sources\install.*
   ```

   If you get the file `install.esd`, make the appropriate substitution when entering the commands given below.
2. Next, enter the following command to determine the index of the Windows image you wish to install.

   ```
   dism  /Get-ImageInfo  /ImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim
   ```

   For my `install.wim` file, the index shown for the name `Windows 10 Pro` was `6`. I will use this value in the commands shown below.
3. This command will copy the Microsoft Windows 10 files to the "BOOTCAMP" volume.

   ```
   dism  /Apply-Image  /ImageFile:D:\sources\install.wim  /index:6 /ApplyDir:W:\  /CheckIntegrity
   ```

   > Note: When entering the above command, the parameter `/name:"Windows 10 Pro"` could have been substituted for `/index:6`.
4. Add the Apple supplied drivers to the drivers store. This can be accomplished by entering the command shown below.

   ```
   dism  /Image:W:\  /Add-Driver  /Driver:D:\$WinPEDriver$  /Recurse  /ForceUnsigned
   ```

   > Note: If any drivers are ineligible, you may see error messages. This is normal, so such error messages can be ignored.

### Write the Boot Files to the System Partition and Boot to Windows

1. Write the boot files to the system partition. The command to use is given below.

   ```
   bcdboot  w:\windows  /s  s:
   ```
2. Enter the command given below to close the Command Prompt Window.

   ```
   exit
   ```
3. Click on the `X` in the red box on the upper right side of the window shown below. When prompted, click on the `Yes` button to restart the Mac. Immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until then Start Manager icons appear.

   [image]
4. Hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while choosing the internal drive icon with the label `Windows`.
5. Follow the directions and complete the installation of Windows 10.
6. When Windows finishes installing, run the Window Support Software installer. Normally this installer starts automatically. If necessary, run the the `setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder on the flash drive with the volume label `WINSTALL`.

### How to Select an Apple Keyboard

The following steps can be execute to select an Apple keyboard. The steps should only be executed after the Window Support Software installer has run.

1. Click on the Window Start button, then select `Settings`.
2. Select `Time & Language`.
3. Select `Language`.
4. Select `Default app language; Default input language; Windows display language`.
5. Select `Options`.
6. Select `Add a keyboard`.
7. Select the appropriate Apple keyboard.
8. Select the original keyboard, then select Remove.

### References:

[UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions)
[Capture and apply Windows, system, and recovery partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-system-and-recovery-partitions)
[DISM Image Management Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)
[Create a Windows 10 Bootable USB Flash Drive on a Mac](http://twocanoes.com/create-a-windows-10-bootable-usb-flash-drive-on-a-mac/)
[Resolving INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE Error after restoring Winclone image](http://twocanoes.com/knowledge-base/resolving-inaccessible_boot_device-error-after-restoring-winclone-image/)
[Is it possible to use Boot Camp with Windows 10 from an external HDD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd/307931#307931)

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping out. I will run this as soon as I get home. Second, would creating those 2 partitions help ? If so, I'd rather create them. I can run a few commands in the windows terminal. I am relatively comfortable with the shell in both linux and windows, but I don't have much (if any) experience with partitioning drives manually, which is why I prefer to follow instructions by someone who knows their stuff rather than risk messing up my system.

Comment: I keep trying to install win, I have an SD card formatted as exFAT, I can select EFI Boot, got past the point where it asks for the serial number, but the Win installation crashes afterwards. Tried 3 different SD cards (I am using an USB adaptor, because if I put the card in the SD card reader, it seems the iMac doesn't "see" it when booting up). Tried with external drive connected via USB. I reseted the PRAM and SMC, I tried formatting the SD cards exFAT & FAT32, I tried all I could think of. got to the S/N part a couple of times, the rest of times the installation just crashed.

Comment: Another thing, I noticed this: https://i.imgur.com/M3GUOzB.png in Disk Utility: there's a small volume of 12GB there. Is that normal ? If not, how can I get rid of it ?

Comment: I updated my answer. My original answer works, but only if installing to `disk0`. If you have a problem, please post a comment.

Comment: I do not know if Windows can be installed using a SD card. I would recommend using a 16 GB or larger flash drive. If you Mac has USB 3 ports, then a USB 3 flash drive would be significantly faster than a USB 2 flash drive. My 2013 iMac, with Mojave installed, has a small volume of 9.3 GB. So, I think this is normal. However, if you had previous volumes with macOS installed in your APFS container, then there could be hidden files that could be erased to reduce the size of used space on these other volumes.

Comment: Sadly, I am not even getting the screen at point #3. I see "Starting setup" (or something like this) and then the iMac reboots. I have tried with a normal USB this time, so not with an SD card. I am running out of patience with this POS. I am about ready to do a full format of the drive, if that would help fix this.

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? If your Mac has a screen, what is the size? For example, my machine is an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013).

Comment: I actually managed to get past that point. Turns out, my phone was charging on a USB-C to USB-C cable connected to the computer, and that, apparently, was causing the windows installer to crash. I don't understand why, it doesn't make any sense to me, but whatever. Disconnected my phone and the setup didn't crash anymore. Thanks to your point by point tutorial I managed to install windows. It's got all its updates now, too - which is what made it crash the first time. So let me say this again: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!!!! YOU ARE AWESOME !!!!

Comment: BTW, my iMac is a 27" 5k 2017 model.